# Structuring data to allow 3rd dimension SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

Currently i have a multiple select query that pulls the data, which than i need to have the contract length split into separate months and having the amount split as well. Heres a simplified example of the current table:

```
Month     Contract Length   Client    Client Details    Amount

Jan'17       12 months      Client1      Details 1      1200
Feb'17        3 months      Client2      Details 2      600
Nov'17       15 months      Client3      Details 3      30000
```

From that i would need to receive something that would look like:

```
Client   Client Details |... Jan'17  Feb'17  Mar'17  Apr'17 .... Sep'17 Oct' 17  Nov'17  Dec'17...| 

Client1  Details 1            100      100     100     100         100    100      100      100
Client2  Details 2                     200     200     200
Client3  Details 3                                                                 2000    2000
```

Was thinking about having a query to add columns for each month of each year and then put that single month value into that specific column, but the data is around 8 years, thus would have a bit too many columns and even if thats the way to go, im still not sure how to formulate such a query. Would there be any suggestions how to approach it?

Thank you,
Lukas

Comment: Where are you displaying this data?  This type of thing is usually best dealt with in your presentation layer.

Comment: A lot of users use excel, thus need to make the table viable for excel pivots

Answer (score 1):

If this is being passed out to SSRS or similar, then your query is fine, let your presentation layer handle it.

If you need this in SQL alone, then search for info on PIVOT TABLES. Its well documented once you know what your looking for.

Comment: Hello, im well familiar with Pivot Tables, however i dont believe theres an easy way to do it with them (using simple pivots and not power pivots or such). The only way for the Pivot to show it that i can think of is adding additional Columns to the table

Comment: If your looking for an output with variable columns rather than fixed, then dynamic SQL is probably the only way to go.  I have an example of dynamic sql that builds a view using the pivot.  You can probably adjust it to just act as a select.  Since it's part of our licve system I won't post here, but can email/PM it across if you want to go down that road.

Comment: It would definitely be very interesting to see an example!

Comment: Just checked more about Dynamic SQL and it looks like the exact way to go. Not too familiar with it yet, thus any suggestions would be very welcomed!

Comment: No problem.  I won't post my live code (security risk), but if you have an email I'll send it privately.

Comment: Sure would be great to see it. Through  views i have used exec stored procedures to allow to query through a pivot live from another server, however in this case not sure how to make it so that it transforms the data like that.

Answer (score 0):

Example of Pivot table usage for this:

```
BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE dbo.PivotExample (Country NVARCHAR(50) NULL
                                  ,Year SMALLINT NOT NULL
                                  ,SalesAmount MONEY NULL
                                  )
GO

INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES  (N'Australia', 2005, 1309047.1978)
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES  (N'Germany', 2006, 521230.8475)
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country
        ,Year
        ,SalesAmount
        )
VALUES  (N'United States'
        ,2007
        ,2838512.3550
        )
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES  (N'France', 2008, 922179.0400)
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES  (N'Australia', 2007, 3033784.2131)
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES  (N'France', 2005, 180571.6920)
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country
        ,Year
        ,SalesAmount
        )
VALUES  (N'United Kingdom'
        ,2006
        ,591586.8540
        )
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES  (N'Canada', 2006, 621602.3823)
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country
        ,Year
        ,SalesAmount
        )
VALUES  (N'United Kingdom'
        ,2005
        ,291590.5194
        )
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country
        ,Year
        ,SalesAmount
        )
VALUES  (N'United States'
        ,2005
        ,1100549.4498
        )
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES  (N'Canada', 2007, 535784.4624)
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES  (N'France', 2007, 1026324.9692)
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES  (N'Germany', 2007, 1058405.7305)
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES  (N'Australia', 2006, 2154284.8835)
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country
        ,Year
        ,SalesAmount
        )
VALUES  (N'United Kingdom'
        ,2008
        ,1210286.2700
        )
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country
        ,Year
        ,SalesAmount
        )
VALUES  (N'United States'
        ,2008
        ,3324031.1600
        )
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES  (N'Germany', 2008, 1076890.7700)
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country
        ,Year
        ,SalesAmount
        )
VALUES  (N'United Kingdom'
        ,2007
        ,1298248.5675
        )
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES  (N'Australia', 2008, 2563884.2900)
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES  (N'Canada', 2005, 146829.8074)
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES  (N'Germany', 2005, 237784.9902)
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES  (N'Canada', 2008, 673628.2100)
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country
        ,Year
        ,SalesAmount
        )
VALUES  (N'United States'
        ,2006
        ,2126696.5460
        )
INSERT  dbo.PivotExample
        (Country, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES  (N'France', 2006, 514942.0131)
GO

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.PivotExample
ORDER BY Country
GO

SELECT  Country
,       [2005]
,       [2006]
,       [2007]
,       [2008]
,       [2009]
,       [2010]
FROM    dbo.PivotExample PIVOT
( SUM(SalesAmount) FOR Year IN ([2005], [2006], [2007], [2008], [2009], [2010]) ) P

--Declare necessary variables
DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get unique values of pivot column  
SELECT   @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME(Year)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Year FROM [dbo].[PivotExample]) AS PivotExample

SELECT   @PivotColumns

--Create the dynamic query with all the values for 
--pivot column at runtime
SET   @SQLQuery = 
    N'SELECT Country, ' +   @PivotColumns + '
    FROM [dbo].[PivotExample] 
    PIVOT( SUM(SalesAmount) 
          FOR Year IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS P'

SELECT   @SQLQuery
--Execute dynamic query
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Credit to http://www.databasejournal.com

Full Link http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/converting-rows-to-columns-pivot-and-columns-to-rows-unpivot-in-sql-server.html

Have a read of the full page, it's pretty good, and what I based my code on.

Comment: Thats very close to what im looking for, will definitely have a good study of that link, thank you!